# JS can't receive JSON data from orion-ld broker, a CORS related issue occurred

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fiware

I use orion-ld context broker

```
{
"orionld version": "post-v1.0.0",
"orion version": "1.15.0-next",
"uptime": "0 d, 0 h, 25 m, 17 s",
"git_hash": "nogitversion",
"compile_time": "Wed Jan 26 15:58:47 UTC 2022",
"compiled_by": "root",
"compiled_in": "",
"release_date": "Wed Jan 26 15:58:47 UTC 2022",
"doc": "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
}
```

If I try to request JSON data in an HTML file via JS like

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open("GET", "http://192.168.0.18:1028/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:OffStreetParking:XXX_102700") ;
myRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/ld+json")       
myRequest.onload = function () {
    console.log(myRequest.responseText);
};
myRequest.send();
```

I got a error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.18:1028/ngsi-ld/v1/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:OffStreetParking:XXX_102700' from origin 'http://192.168.0.18' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

If I login to the docker container console and check the variable ORIONLD_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN, it contains the necessary value "__ALL".

### What could be wrong here?

**Update at 03/01/2022:**
Now I create a [simple webpage](http://herten.homelinux.net/%7Eknigge/orion-ld_test02.html) based on JS functions from `NGSI.js`, as Jason Fox yesterday suggested. There you are able to test the "v2" related calls to the orion-ld and the "ld" related calls.
In the browser console, you can see the logged results.
You can also change the orion-ld URL on the website so that you can test your environment.
Nevertheless, the CORS settings for orion-ld server did not work as expected. 'v2' calls work well, 'ld' calls failed.
I create my orion-ld test environment with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  orion-ld:
    image: fiware/orion-ld
    hostname: orion-ld
    ports:
      - "1029:1026"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db  
    environment:
      ORIONLD_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN: __ALL
      corsOrigin: __ALL
      ORIONLD_CORS_MAX_AGE: 86400
    command: -dbhost mongo-db-vm -logLevel DEBUG

  mongo-db:
    image: mongo:3.6 
    hostname: mongo-db-vm
    volumes:
      - /SOMEWHERE/data:/data
```

Please test my and your environment on [simple webpage](http://herten.homelinux.net/%7Eknigge/orion-ld_test02.html) and give feedback.

Comment: *"What could be wrong here?"* - well, the message "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." does not leave a lot of room for interpretation. Double check your server configuration.

Comment: Exactly, your server does not return that header. Check the configuration.

Comment: Take a look at the [ngsijs library](https://github.com/Ficodes/ngsijs) for an example of how to successfully enable CORS with a context broker and access it using JavaScript.

Comment: Now I change HTML file and use only the examples from NGSI.js
But the same issue occured.
The `docker-compose.yml` contains:
`orion-ld:
    image: fiware/orion-ld
    environment:
      ORIONLD_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN: '__ALL'
      corsOrigin: __ALL`
If I restart the container and check the environment variables, I see the expected settings:
`[root@orion-ld /]# echo $ORIONLD_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN
__ALL
[root@orion-ld /]# echo $corsOrigin
__ALL
[root@orion-ld /]# echo $ORIONLD_CORS_MAX_AGE
86400`

Comment: But If I use my [HTML file](http://herten.homelinux.net/~knigge/orion-ld_test01.html) in a Chrome browser (with Console output), I can see, that all `connection.v2` calls works as expected. But all `connections.ld` calls will not work as described.
Could it be, that the CORS settings will not be used in orion-ld v1.15.0-next ?

Answer (score 0):

Orion-LD architect and developer here. All Orion-LD has about CORS is what was inherited from Orion. This is the first time anybody asks for CORS for Orion-LD, so, I'll try to fix it asap.

Comment: I thought, that Orion-LD works in the same kind of art as Orion does. If I'm able to read ( connection.v2.getEntity ) and write ( connection.v2.createEntity ) entities with JS, I expect it should work with ld related JS functions ( connection.ld.getEntity ,  connection.ld.createEntity ) too. After I run into the CORS issue with ld JS functions, I thought that the existing docker parameter ORIONLD_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN should and would help here. Nice, that the isn't on my side and that Fiware will fix the issue soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it is inconsistent, I agree. What will happen now is probably that CORS support will be removed from the NGSIv2 requests. As Stefan mentions below, it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is all about a local development setup. Thus you probably call your frontend at "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", leading to the CORS-issue when it calls orion at "192.168.0.18". You basically have 2 options to still make it work:

1. disable CORS in your browser when developing. Concrete solution depends on your browser.
2. Put Orion-LD on localhost, thus calling it with the same origin as your frontend. The docker-compose snippet that you posted already puts orion on "localhost:1029"/"127.0.0.1:1029"(see ports-section). Thus, you should configure the orion endpoint in your frontend to "localhost:1029"/"127.0.0.1:1029"(depending on the address you use when calling orion) instead of the current container-ip(e.g. "192.168.0.18:1028")

I do not think it worth implementing the CORS-support directly in Orion-LD, since this is not a real deployment scenario. In real-world scenarios, you would have one of the following:

1. A very small scenario, that does not even use any kind of security framework and only one broker instance. In such environments, its very unusual to have the frontend running on a different origin.
2. A security framework between orion and the frontend. In this case, the requests from the frontend will never directly reach the broker, but the security-layer instead. Thus, the security component has to provide the CORS-header.
3. A scenario with any kind of additional infrastructure(most probably a load-balancer or f.e. an lb+an ingress controller in k8s-environemnts). Similar to scenario 2, this would lead to no request directly reaching the broker and the component between frontend and broker needs to handle CORS.

Comment: Part 1:

1. I try to disable CORS in Chrome ([howto](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)), but it seems not to work.
2. I like to create some JS code examples (in HTML) for developers, how to use Orion-ld ngsi-ld API on the remote side. The local installation of Orion-ld isn't the proper way if developers should use a remote Orion-ld instance.
Part 2:
1. I agree completely.
2. I agree too. In the production environment, we will use API Umbrella.
---
But for the developing stage, it makes sense to connect to remote orion-ld without a security layer.

Comment: Hi, if you really want to run Orion-LD that way, I would recommend a small proxy in front of it that adds the CORS-header. You can find an example here: https://medium.com/pareture/simple-docker-nginx-cors-reverse-proxy-5202a3445847